# Timer in Ajax - Preemption

Tags: javascript, ajax

So this thing was going in my mind for a long time whether the timer that is given in an AJAx after which it has to send another request, what if it is smaller than the actual time taken by the requested file to complete its operation.

for example, consider the below code,

```
<div class="item"></div>
<script>
function timeLeft() {
  $(".item").each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    var dataString = {s: "//some data", st: "<?echo $stamp?>"};
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "get_content_home.php",
      dataType: "html",
      data: dataString, 
      success: function(result) {
        $this.html(result);
      }
    });
  });
}
window.setInterval(function() {
  timeLeft();
}, 100);
</script>
```

the timer given here is 100ms and the file get_content_home.php will be requested every 100m. What if get_content_home.php takes 500ms to complete its operations. Will the get_content_home.php be preempted and will be requested again? or will the timer wait and delay itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The interval has no idea what `timeLeft` is doing.  It will keep firing `timeLeft` every 100ms regardless of whether the request has completed or not.  Because of that, you can definitely have the request callbacks clobbering one another and potentially overwriting one another.  What exactly are you trying to do?  You need to chain your request sequence rather than have them completely ignorant of one another.

Comment: Also, consider that if request `r0` takes 1000ms, but `r1` takes 500ms, you are going to populate with the response from `r1` but then overwrite with the data from `r0` a few hundred ms later.  This is another reason to make your requests aware of one another rather than fire'n'forgetting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worse than you thought since the ajax request is in a loop.

What's gonna happen is actually :

1. `window.setInterval` call `timeLeft`
2. `timeLeft` call the AJAX request to `get_content_home.php`one time for each `.item` element.
3. Let's say one AJAX call take 500ms, you'll do this five time before the first AJAX request return something (hence 5x`number of .item` calls before one result).

To stop this craziness, put your AJAX call outside of the loop and put the `window.setInterval` in the AJAX callback function:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "get_content_home.php",
  dataType: "html",
  data: dataString, 
  success: function(result) {
    $this.html(result);
    window.setTimeOut(function() {
      timeLeft();
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

and call `timeLeft();` just once at the start.