# Ajax too slow - Recursion

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, recursion

A ajax code that i am using to request a page is consuming too much memory and is making the browser slow and everything lag. It seems like there is recursion going on and i dont know of any way to prevent it. Here is what the code looks like.

```
$(".item").each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    var dataString = {s: "<?echo $_SESSION['currentview_'.$stamp]?>", r:"<?echo $search_usernumber?>", st: "<?echo $stamp?>"};
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    function timeLeft() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_content_home.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data: dataString, 
            success: function(result) {
                $this.html(result);
                //console.log("a");
                window.setInterval(function() {
                    timeLeft();
                }, 500);
            }
        });
    }
    timeLeft();
});
```

How can i solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're calling the function every half second and settings a new interval each time. That is probably the main reason for the browser getting bogged down and slow, because you keep adding new timers every 1/2 second

Comment: using `setInterval` in the callback causes `timeLeft` to be scheduled once per 500ms *each* time there is a success... You have other problems, but this is a big one

Comment: How is this different from your 2 other questions?  They all seem like they are asking the same thing.

Comment: Creating a JavaScript object by hand using `{s: "<?php echo ...?>", ...}` is terrible. Look at PHP's `json_encode` instead and parse it on the JavaScript side using `JSON.parse`

Comment: yes @zero298 these are related to ajax because whenever i try to address a problem, a new problem arises that i cant find the solution of.

Comment: Just make `setTimeout(timeLeft, 10)` it may help

Comment: Please see my updated solution.  It should be able to address each of the issues that you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **are** recursing and you shouldn't be using this form of nested `setInterval`.  Doing this, will cause an explosion of interval instances.  Instead of using `setInterval`, schedule additional requests using `setTimeout`.

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) will fire and continue firing every interval until you tell it to stop.

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) will fire once.

---

Let's consider the following code which should address some of the issues you are having in this question as well as your other 2 questions.

First off, as we said before, don't use `setInterval` unless you actually want it to run forever.  Additionally, don't **nest** the `setInterval` creations unless you actually mean to.

Instead, let's create a recursive function `getTimeLeft()` that will handle firing the request and scheduling the next check for time left after some duration.

This example also mocks the `$.ajax()` function so that you can see the function in action since we don't have an actual back end to use.

```js
// Fake server side data to keep track of time lefts
const timeLefts = {
  foo: 0,
  bar: 0,
  fizz: 0,
  buzz: 0
};
const timeLeftsUpdateInterval = setInterval(() => {
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(timeLefts)) {
    timeLefts[key] = Math.min(val + Math.random() * 10, 100);
  }
  if (Object.entries(timeLefts).every(([k, v]) => v >= 100)) {
    clearInterval(timeLeftsUpdateInterval);
  }
}, 1000);

// Mock $.ajax function to stub sending AJAX requests
function $ajax(kwargs) {
  return {
    done: cb => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        cb(timeLefts[kwargs.data.x]);
      }, 500);
    }
  };
}

// We will check for an update every second after the last request finishes
const timeLeftCheckInterval = 1000;

// Continuously check to see how much time is left for an element
function getTimeLeft(el) {
  // Make our request data
  const dataString = {
    s: "<?echo $_SESSION['currentview_'.$stamp]?>",
    r: "<?echo $search_usernumber?>",
    st: "<?echo $stamp?>",
    // My custom property to make this work
    x: el.dataset.item
  };

  // Make our request to get the time left
  const req = $ajax({ // Using our mock $.ajax
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_content_home.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: dataString
  });

  // Once the request has finished
  req.done(data => {
    // Set the time left to the element
    el.innerHTML = data;

    // Have some condition so that you don't check for time left forever
    // Eventually there will be no time left right?  Why keep checking?
    if (data.timeleft <= 0) return;

    // Schedule another round of checking for time left after some duration
    setTimeout(() => {
      getTimeLeft(el);
    }, timeLeftCheckInterval);
  });
}

// Kick off getting timeleft for all .items
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item"))
  .forEach(el => getTimeLeft(el));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item" data-item="foo"></li>
  <li class="item" data-item="bar"></li>
  <li class="item" data-item="fizz"></li>
  <li class="item" data-item="buzz"></li>
</ul>
```

This code will address the issue that you are having in [2 Ajax non-blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50676033/691711) because each element will have it's own logic of going and fetching time left and updating itself.

This also addresses the issue that you are potentially facing in [Timer in Ajax - Preemption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50702090/691711) because now the element won't check to see how much time is left again until after the previous check is finished.